# Java compareTo not correctly sorting strings containing symbols

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting, unicode

I have a java program that builds a max heap, calls Heapify and sorts any list. Currently it will sort the alphabet with no issues, and even a list of strings like `apple, addle, azzle` with no problems. Below is a screenshot of input to the program, which takes the number of items to sort at the first line, and the list below it:

[image]

The green is input that I know is already sorted correctly. If you check the [unicode table](https://unicode-table.com/en/#0059) you can see that the green list is sorted correctly. However my program's output is not correct (in white).

Below is a snippet of my Heapify() code:

```
//takes the maxheap(array) and begins sorting starting with the root node
public void Heapify(String[] A, int i)
{
    if( i > (max_size - 2) )
    {
        System.out.println("\nHeapify exceeded, here are the values:");
        System.out.println("max_size = " + max_size);
        System.out.println("i = " + i);
        return;
    }

    //if the l-child or r-child is going to exceed array, stop
    if( (2 * i) > max_size || ((2 * i) + 1) > max_size )
        return;

    String leftChild = getChild("l", i);    //get left child value
    String rightChild = getChild("r", i);   //get right child value

    if (  (A[i].compareTo(leftChild) > 0) && (A[i].compareTo(rightChild) > 0)  )
        return; //i node is greater than its left and right child node, Heapify is done

    //if left is greater than right, switch the current and left node
    if( leftChild.compareTo(rightChild) > 0 )
    {
        //Swap i and left child
        Swap( i, (2 * i) );
        Heapify(this.h, (2 * i));
    } else {
        //Swap i and right child
        Swap( i, ((2 * i) + 1) );
        Heapify(this.h, ((2 * i) + 1) );
    }

}
```

Ignoring the conditions in the beginning of the method, you can see that my comparisons on the strings simply takes place with the standard `String.compareTo()` in java. Why can't this sort the strings containing the symbols correctly? NOTE that I do not need a custom comparator, I simply need the symbols contained in strings (any symbol on the keyboard for that matter) to be evaluated for their unicode representation. The javadoc for `compareTo` reads:

> Compares two strings lexicographically. The comparison is based on the Unicode value of each character in the strings. The character sequence represented by this String object is compared lexicographically to the character sequence represented by the argument string. The result is a negative integer if this String object lexicographically precedes the argument string. The result is a positive integer if this String object lexicographically follows the argument string. The result is zero if the strings are equal; compareTo returns 0 exactly when the equals(Object) method would return true.

Stating that it uses unicode, any suggestions to my issue?

test file(already sorted): [test.txt](https://hastebin.com/manupizure.pl)
code files: [Main.java](https://hastebin.com/nihoripoyi.cs), [MaxHeap.java](https://hastebin.com/jonunoyowo.cs)

Comment: Please submit a comment for your "-1" as to a reason why you are downvoting this question, rather than doing a "drive-by downvote"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You aren't using `compareTo()`, you are using `compareToIgnoreCase()`, which explains that each character is converted to upper case, then that character is converted to lower case.

Your strings differ in their 6th letter, which are `Y`, `n`, and `]`. After conversion as documented, the characters are `y`, `n`, and `]`. So the strings are ordered lexicographically as `]`, `n`, `Y`.

Comment: I've actually changed to using `compareTo` instead, and am still getting the exact same result? So with no conversion i have `Y`, `]`, `n`, which lexicographically should stay in the same order..

Comment: @Chisx Okay, post a [mcve] and we can check it further.

Comment: I have posted hastebin links to the complete code files involved, as well as a link for a test.txt to "<" feed into program if using Unix command line, can paste two into command line app too obviously.

Comment: I found the error. It turns out I still had a `compareToIgnoreCase()` being used in code in a different method.

Answer (score 2):

You are using `compareToIgnoreCase`, in which the [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#compareToIgnoreCase(java.lang.String)) states:

> This method returns an integer whose sign is that of calling compareTo with normalized versions of the strings where case differences have been eliminated by calling Character.toLowerCase(Character.toUpperCase(character)) on each character.

So in your example, ']' and 'n' are indeed before 'y'.

Comment: I've actually changed to using `compareTo` instead, and am still getting the exact same result? So with no conversion i have `Y`, `]`, `n`, which lexicographically should stay in the same order..